# JavaScript sandbox that makes it less dangerous?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, javascript, sandbox

Should we anticipate Tor to develop/integrate something that will make JavaScript less potentially dangerous, in a way that provides websites with basic JavaScript functionalities while still protecting users' privacy by disabling the unfavored stuff?

Comment: No, javascript isn't especially dangerous.